# Given $f \in \Omega(g)$, prove that $\mathcal{O}(g) \subseteq \mathcal{O}(f)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

My proof goes like this:

By definition

$f \in \{ g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}|\exists \beta > 0 \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \forall  n \geq n_0 : 0 \leq f(n) \leq \beta g(n) \}$

therefore $0 \leq \beta_f g(n) \leq f(n) \,\forall n \geq n_f$ .

Let $h \in \mathcal{O}(g):=\{f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}|\exists \alpha > 0 \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \forall  n \geq n_0 : 0 \leq f(n) \leq \alpha g(n)\}$

and therefore $0 \leq h(n) \leq \alpha_h g(n)\,\forall n \geq n_h$.

Rearrange the inequality to $\frac{h(n)}{\alpha_h} \leq g(n)$.

Substitute g(n) into $0 \leq \beta_f g(n) \leq f(n) \,\forall n \geq n_f$.

Resulting to
$0 \leq \frac{\beta_f}{\alpha_h} h(n) \leq f(n) \,\forall n \geq max \{ n_{h}, n_{f}\}$

Rearrange inequality:
$0 \leq h(n) \leq \frac{\alpha_h}{\beta_f} f(n)$

This means
$h \in \mathcal{O}(f)$
and therefore $\mathcal{O}(g) \subseteq \mathcal{O}(f)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why did you use $\mathcal{N}$ and $\Bbb N$? Those denote different sets? Also, you forgot to use `$` in the last line. If you don't show a little effort writing your questions don't expect other users putting much effort answering them. The good news is that you can edit your question.

Comment: This post contains no question.

Comment: 1) Since $g$ is fixed, it should not appear as a variable in your "$f \in \{ g:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R\mid\dots\}$". Choose another letter, e.g. $f \in \{ k:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R\mid\dots\}.$ 2) Your definition of $f\in\Omega(g)$ is wrong. It should be (assuming $f,g\ge0$): $$f \in \{ k:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R\mid\exists \beta > 0 \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \forall  n \geq n_0 :k(n)\ge \beta g(n) \}.$$ 3) Keep it simple, writing rather directly$$\exists \beta > 0 \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \forall  n \geq n_0 :f(n)\ge \beta g(n) .$$Same remarks 1 and 3 for $h\in\mathcal O(g).$